# ImportError: cannot import name 'port_by_scheme' from 'urllib3.connection'

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10

I tried to open Google via `selenium` but i got this error.Can anyone explain ?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Dimitar\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get ("https://www.facebook.com")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Dimitar/PycharmProjects/helloworld/new.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver

  File "C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver

  File "C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection

  File "C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import urllib3

  File "C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (

  File "C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .connection import (

ImportError: cannot import name 'port_by_scheme' from 'urllib3.connection' (C:\Users\Dimitar\PycharmProjects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py)
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to your question? The code you ran, what you were expecting, and format the output a bit more properly (use code blocks).

Comment: Sorry @MaJoR i'm new to StackOverflow i'm still learning how to post questions.The thing is i'm trying to run **InstaPy** bot from **github** and can't open Chrome.I import `webdriver` from `selenium` put the chromedriver path to variable and when try to run i get this erro mentioned above

Comment: I am unable to replicate the above problem. Maybe, there is some issue with the virtualenv or some modules. :/ Try creating a new clean virtualenv, and try the above code

Comment: I will try thank you for spending time to solve this @MaJoR